# Make QTableWidgetItem non-editable, but still able to select parts of a string

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

I have a QTableWidget with data that I would like the user to be able to double-click on, and copy a specific part of the text. The only thing I want to disable is the user's ability to change that text, meaning that setting the flag `~Qt.ItemIsEditable` is too restrictive. How can I achieve this in PyQt5?

Comment: qtreewidget or QTableWidget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: This solution works for all kinds of classes that inherit from QAbstractItemView like QTableWidget or QTreeWidget.

A possible solution is to use a modify the editor to be read-only through a delegate.

```py
class StyledItemDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, *args):
        editor = super().createEditor(*args)
        if isinstance(editor, QLineEdit):
            editor.setReadOnly(True)
        return editor
```

```
delegate = StyledItemDelegate(view)
view.setItemDelegate(delegate)
```